# ASP.NET Core 6 Web API memory deployed in OpenShift not released

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, openshift, .net-6.0

I have a basic API deployed to an Openshift pod with configuration:

[image: containers: - resources: limits: cpu: 300m memory: 512Mi requests: cpu: 300m memory: 512Mi]

I did a load test with thousands of calls and the memory used was close to the limit.

When I stopped the calls, the memory used did not return to the level before the start of the load tests.

I created this configuration in the `.csproj`:

[image]

The API is similar to the one automatically generated by Visual Studio, the `WeatherForeCast` and therefore without potential agents causing this problem.

The API is on .NET 6 version.

Has anyone experienced a similar problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Does it work if you perform the load test for the second time while the memory is high? It doesn't have to release memory just after it's done. But if the memory pressure is there it should and the second load test should work.

Comment: @PawełŁukasik thank you very much for your answer. Yes it works when we test for the second time. My concern is because this API has a very high number of calls per hour, around about 50000 calls per hour. 
We are even thinking about testing other frameworks like Quarkus.